# Does fgets ignore certain character combinations?

Tags: php

I'm using fgets to read a file line by line.  Certain string combinations are being ignored.  I'm guessing this is being picked up as an escape character, but I don't understand.

My code is:

```
$myFile = $_GET['filename'];

$file = fopen($myFile, "r");

while (!feof($file))
{
   $currentLine = fgets($file);
   print $currentLine;
}
```

And my file is:

```
15:37:33 Me <Washington  USA>  outdoor
15:39:34 Me <Washington USA>  outdoor
15:41:36 Me <208 Terrace Ct SE USA>  outdoor
15:43:37 Me <305 Glyndon St SE USA>  indoor
```

Yet the output is only this:

```
15:37:33 me outdoor 15:39:34 me outdoor 15:41:36 me <208 Terrace Ct SE USA> outdoor 15:43:37 me <305 Glyndon St SE USA> indoor
```

Why are the <'s followed by characters ignored but not the <'s followed by numbers?

Comment: Are you printing this on browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser interprets the text between < and > as an HTML tag (at least the ones that don't start with a digit). If you look at the source of your page, I'm sure you'll find the complete text.

To solve your issue, use PHP's htmlentities() function like this:

```
print htmlentities($currentLine);
```

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you viewing it on the page directly or in the source?
Have the feeling that browser hides them :))

Comment: testing by writing directly to the browser.  How else would I test? <- serious question, I'm a noob

Comment: see page source in broswer

Comment: because you did not use htmlentities() function, and your broswer thinks you made up a new HTML tags or something. In fact, it won't process the ones starting with the number by W3C rules

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the problematics of opening files directly from the `$_GET` array for a moment, you need to turn the brackets into HTML entities. To show the newlines correctly you can either add `<br>` to the end of each line, or use `<pre>` and `\n` like so:

```
$myFile = $_GET['filename'];
$file = fopen($myFile, "rb");
echo '<pre>';
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    echo rtrim(htmlentities($line)), "\n";
}
```

Now, opening files like this. It is a really, really bad idea. If you are only using the code for your own use then okay, but even so it may cause problems that you have not thought about. The best thing is to never use client-provided data for opening files, but if you have to then make sure the path is clean and does not contain malicious stuff (such as a preceding slash or dot, etc).

Comment: I understand I'm skirting coding practices.  This is an internal prototype only.